# Is it possible to add literal character strings to the front of a column name and immediately after the SELECT keyword?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to get the table to display my information so that it comes out like a sentence like this: **The Rockets team has 25 players and receives a discount of 10 percent**. However, I'm having trouble trying to get the *The* and the *percent* parts of the sentence to show up.

This is what I've typed out so far:

```
SELECT name || ' team has '|| number_of_players || ' players and receives a discount of ' || discount AS "Team Information"
FROM teams;
```

And this is what I'm getting as the results:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a SELECT list you can add literals before and after columns even for the first colum and for the last one:

```
SELECT 
'The ' || name || ' team has '|| number_of_players || 
' players and receives a discount of ' || 
discount || ' percent' AS "Team Information"
FROM teams;
```